# Wrong file include on IIS

Tags: php, iis, path

I've got the following directory-file structure;

```
/index.php
/head.inc    (upper)
/subdir/page.php
/subdir/head.inc   (lower)
```

In /subdir/page.php I have a redirection to upper level index.php

```
header("location: ../index.php");
```

In index.php file there's include('head.inc') directive.

On Apache server correct head.inc (upper) is loaded - head.inc from the same (webroot) directory where index.php resides. On IIS the incorrect head.inc (lower) is loaded - head.inc from /subdir/ where page.php resides which made a redirection! Is this a bug in ISS?

Comment: Take note that by standards, location headers should be **absolute**. Try fixing that and see if the problem persists. (It's a long shot, but what the heck)

Comment: I need to keep relative path since sometimes I deploy my web app on web server root and sometime in WebApp subfolder. However how's that IIS decides on its own what file to load (from root or from subfolder). I renamed upper head.inc into top.inc and changed include('top.inc'). Previously IIS loaded .inc file from subdir and now from the root dir where index.php is as expected! Strange IIS behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try generating your own, full path. Examples of this might be:

```
// Get the parent directory
$parent_directory = basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

header("Location: $parent_directory/index.php");
```

Comment: ./ in form of dirname(__FILE__) and ../ in form of dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) work the same on both servers IIS and Apache and are helpful